# trying to create a dynamic swiper

Tags: php, database

I'm trying to create a dynamic swiper that is able to automatically update itself whenever I make changes in the database. The problem that I've encountered right now is that I've got 6 pictures and description in the swiper but all of them only retrieve from the first field from my database.
[Old screenshot of the page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8ukh.jpg) As you can see from the first screenshot I am able to retrieve the data which is the picture and the description from the database, but only repeatingly retrieve from the first field of the database for all the 6 results. [Able to show it in the php area.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVj54.jpg)  [Only the first slider is working when i called the function in html.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpClD.jpg)
Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db");
$result = make_query($connect);

function fetch_array(&$array) {
    // Grab the first value from the array
    $return = current($array);
    // remove the value we just grabbed 
    array_shift($array);
    // if what we have is an array spit it out, else return false
    return is_array($return) ? $return : false;
}

function make_query($connect) { 
    $query = "SELECT * FROM db.slider ORDER BY p_id ASC";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    return $result;
}

function make_slide_indicators($result) {
    $output = ''; 
    $count = 0;

    for($i = 0;$i<mysqli_num_rows($result);$i++) {
    //for($i = 0;$i<count($result);$i++) {
        if ($i == 0) {
            $output .= '<li data-target="#" data-slide-to="'.$i.'" class="active"></li>';
        } else {
            $output .= '<li data-target="#" data-slide-to="'.$i.'"></li>';
        }
         $count++ === $count = $count + 1;
    }
    return $output;
}

function make_slides($result) {
    $output = '';
    $count = 0;
    
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    //while($row = fetch_array($result)) {
        // Not needed as the output is the same
        if($count == 0) {
        $output .= '
    <div class="swiper-slide platform">
        <img src="'.$row["p_img"].'" alt="'.$row["p_name"].'" />
        <div class="swiper-slide platform">
            <h3>'.$row["p_desc"].'</h3>
        </div>
    </div>';
        // Not used at the moment
         $count++;
        }
    }
    return $output;
}

$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db");
$result = make_query($connect);
$result = [['p_img' => 'img','p_name' => 'name','p_desc' => 'desc'],['p_img' => 'img','p_name' => 'name','p_desc' => 'desc'],['p_img' => 'img','p_name' => 'name','p_desc' => 'desc'],['p_img' => 'img','p_name' => 'name','p_desc' => 'desc']];

echo make_slide_indicators($result);
echo PHP_EOL;
echo make_slides($result);
?>
```

Comment: I recommend taking a peek at [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Taking a quick look at PHP manual, `mysqli_query` returns a [`mysqli_result`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php), which provides you with methods such as `fetch_all()` and `fetch_assoc()` to retrieve your results. But as @KimHallberg pointed, you need to improve your question in order for people to understand the issue you're facing and help you.

Comment: Alright guys, sorry it's my first time on asking question. Will do better next time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with databases use while instead of foreach. The problem you're having is that mysqli_result is not exactly what you think it is, You can have a look here:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php

Here is a clean version of the code provided. I didn't setup a db for this so to test the logic I implemented a dummy function to work on a set array. I hope the comments are helpful.

```
function fetch_array(&$array) {
    // Grab the first value from the array
    $return = current($array);
    // remove the value we just grabbed 
    array_shift($array);
    // if what we have is an array spit it out, else return false
    return is_array($return) ? $return : false;
}

function make_query($connect) { 
    $query = "SELECT * FROM db.slider ORDER BY p_id ASC";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    return $result;
}

function make_slide_indicators($result) {
    $output = ''; 
    $count = 0;

    //for($i = 0;$i<mysqli_num_rows($result);$i++) {
    for($i = 0;$i<count($result);$i++) {
        if ($i == 0) {
            $output .= '<li data-target="#" data-slide-to="'.$i.'" class="active"></li>';
        } else {
            $output .= '<li data-target="#" data-slide-to="'.$i.'"></li>';
        }
        // $count++ === $count = $count + 1;
    }
    return $output;
}

function make_slides($result) {
    $output = '';
    // $count = 0;
    
    //while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    while($row = fetch_array($result)) {
        // Not needed as the output is the same
        //if($count == 0) { ... } else { ... }
        $output .= '
    <div class="swiper-slide platform">
        <img src="'.$row["p_img"].'" alt="'.$row["p_name"].'" />
        <div class="swiper-slide platform">
            <h3>'.$row["p_desc"].'</h3>
        </div>
    </div>';
        // Not used at the moment
        // $count++;
    }
    return $output;
}

//$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db");
//$result = make_query($connect);
$result = [['p_img' => 'img','p_name' => 'name','p_desc' => 'desc'],['p_img' => 'img','p_name' => 'name','p_desc' => 'desc'],['p_img' => 'img','p_name' => 'name','p_desc' => 'desc'],['p_img' => 'img','p_name' => 'name','p_desc' => 'desc']];

echo make_slide_indicators($result);
echo PHP_EOL;
echo make_slides($result);
```

The biggest difference in the code is that we're using mysqli_num_rows() in make_slide_indicators(). We don't need to fetch all the data from the mysql result, we just need the number of rows we received.

That solves another problem. If you go trough the whole result with mysqli_fetch_assoc() the next time you would try to work on the same result you would only get the last value. The result has in internal pointer that moves a position forward when a line is read.

If you would ever want to go over a result more then once you'd need to use mysqli_data_seek(). Have a look here:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.data-seek.php

If you run the code as is You'll see that the logic works correctly. If you still have an issue when you switch to the db connection the problem is there. Here's a quick debug check for you:

```
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db");
$result = make_query($connect);

echo "Number of rows: ".mysqli_num_rows($result).PHP_EOL;

while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    var_dump($r);
}
```

Comment: Changed it already, but sadly it's still the same :(

Comment: Mate I need to run for the moment but try editing your question and pasting in your code there. Will make it more readable also reflect the changes you've made. We'll have a look at it in a few hours

Comment: I just reread your question you're getting 6 results with only the first field in them? or 1 result with all fields? Whatever the case if you're still having that problem run the debug on the end of my answer and add it to the question

Comment: Yeah i'm getting 6 results but only able to get from the first field from the database.
Edit: I've re-edit the question already and changed the code accordingly but still wasn't showing any result, check out the new screenshot.

Comment: Run the debug on the end of my answer, that should give us some information

Comment: It shows "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function make_query() in C:\xampp\htdocs\database\Index.php:3 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\database\Index.php on line 3"
Line 3=$result = make_query($connect);

Comment: copy the make_query function to the script

Comment: It works! It shows all the data from my database

Comment: right, so now if you look at the code i wrote you'll see there are two lines with while in them, the one commented out is to be used with the database, the other one is for testing. Same thing goes for the for loop in make_slide_indicators. Simply swap the comments on those and presto, we should be good

Comment: Swapped out both of the comment's one but i get this error "Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: mysqli_num_rows(): Argument #1 ($result) must be of type mysqli_result, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Inari\Index.php:24 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Inari\Index.php(24): mysqli_num_rows(Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Inari\Index.php(61): make_slide_indicators(Array) #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Inari\Index.php on line 24"  Line 24= for loop function.

Comment: Same goes for the comments on the bottom. Right now the $result is set to a dummy array. You need to make the mysql connection and execute the query. I understand that you might be in a hurry but try to have a read trough the code and understand how it's working.

Comment: Sorry man, i'm new to php and programming so kinda blur about all these things. But I will definitely re-understand the whole thing once it's working. Can you check if I write the code correctly? I've re-edit it in the question part. Thanks man appreciate it.

Comment: Just remove the $connect, $result, $result near the bottom. and the line in make_slide_indicators $count++ === $count = $count+1; the === operator means that something is exactly equal to the other side. In this case i was saying that both sides of the operator do exactly the same thing. So instead of writing $count = $count+1; you can simply do a $count++ and PHP will do the magic in the background. In make_slides remove the if statement or it will only print one result.

Comment: Alright, the code works bro! Appreciate it but one more question, I will need to call the function in html in order to let it show in the slider right. So the problem is I am able to only show the first result in the first slide and when I call the function in the other slide it won't show. I have inserted two new photos in the question.

Comment: No idea what sort of slider you're using. It's hard to say anything at this point. I assume you have some js that will move things around? Might be a good time to have a look at what you got and formulate a new question ;)

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot man! Appreciate the help as i've been stuck for almost a week about the loop problem. Really helps a lot! And yes i have some js that is able to be swiped left or right, will go ask it in the js section!

Comment: No problem mate. Just provide all the information. The script you're using the source view of the slider etc.

Comment: Alright man, thanks for the tips! You sir, made my day and have a nice day!